# Combine Text and Formula using Concatenate and if cell is not blank Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  =CONCATENATE("THIS IS THE EXECUTION PAGE of the Agreement made between "&A1&" "&A2&" as Developer and "&A3&" as Purchaser(s),"",IF(A4<>"","and "&A5&" "&A6&" as Proprietor","") in respect of Parcel No. "&A7&",""")
```

*With the formula above, I'm trying to achieve a sentence where If cell A4 is blank, it will be :

**THIS IS THE EXECUTION PAGE of the Agreement made between A1 A2 as Developer and A3 as purchaser(s) in respect of Parcel No. A7***

*AND where if cell A4 is not blank, it will be :

**THIS IS THE EXECUTION PAGE of the Agreement made between A1 A2 as Developer and A3 as purchaser(s) and A5 A6 as proprietor in respect of Parcel No. A7***

But it won't allow me to. Please advise where gone wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your data.  Can you do a better job of explaining what the meaning of this sentence is?

Comment: question edited. see if it's clearer for you or not.

Comment: See my revised answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
="THIS IS THE EXECUTION PAGE of the Agreement made between " & A1 & " " & A2 & " as Developer and " & A3 & " as Purchaser(s) " & IF(ISBLANK(A4), "",  "and "  & A5 & " " & A6 & " as Proprietor") & " in respect of Parcel No. " & A7
```

Comment: almost, but not what I want, i edited my question, should be clearer.

Comment: See revised answer